# Override setEdit in UITableViewController: where does the call come from?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

When the user taps on Edit or Done in the top left corner of a `UITableViewController`, I need to change some things (in addition to what Apple does automatically).

I override `setEditing()`, do my visual changes there. Works fine.

The method `setEditing()` of the `UITableViewController` is also called, when the user swipes left on a `UITableViewCell`.

Here comes the problem: like Apple, I need to do important things differently, when a user swipes left on a cell.

How do I know which user action (tapping on edit or swiping left on a cell) caused the `setEditing()` call?

Answer (score 1):

To tell if a swipe caused editing to occur, add the `UITableViewDelegate` callback `tableView(_:willBeginEditingRowAt:)` to your code. Set an internal flag in this function and when `setEditing` is called check this flag.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by trying @bbarnhart's answer:

When overriding `tableView(_:willBeginEditingRowAt:)` then `setEditing(true)` is not called at the begin of a cell swipe.

When overriding `tableView(_:didEndEditingRowAt:)` then `setEditing(false)` is not called at the end of the cell editing.

So just the presence of these overrides solves the problem.