# UIContextualAction triggers setEditing = true, how to disable this?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uicontextualaction

I just implemented `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` and `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` to add swipe actions to my `UITableViewCell`s.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration
```

This triggers (on my UITableViewController) `func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)` to be called with `editing = true`, which in turn also triggers my editing animation and other changes that I want when going into edit mode. (The contextual actions are not related to editing/deleting).

I don't want this, but have yet to find a way to disable this behaviour, even just detecting that `setEditing` is called via the swipe actions.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am afraid that's how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by triggering the "real" edit mode differently.

On my `UITableViewController`:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var realEditMode: Bool = false

  func setRealEditing(_ editing: Bool) {
    realEditMode = editing
    setEditing(realEditMode, animated: true)
  }

  // See Note 1 below
  @available(iOS 11.0, *)
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration {
    guard let item = itemForIndexPath(indexPath) else {
      return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])
    }

    if realEditMode {
      return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [
        buildActionConfiguration(.delete, fromIndexPath: indexPath)
      ])
    } else {
      return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [
        buildActionConfiguration(.read, fromIndexPath: indexPath)
      ])
    }
  }

  @available(iOS 11.0, *)
  func buildActionConfiguration(_ action: MyCellActionEnum, fromIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
    // logic to build `UIContextualAction`
  }
}
```

And in my `UITableViewCell` check if the `editing` flag is set by manual triggering or by swipe edit triggering:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
  var myTableViewController: MyTableViewController?

  override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if editing && !(myTableViewController?.realEditMode ?? true) {
        return
    }

    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
  }
}
```

Then on the edit buttons in the UI I changed `setEditing(true/false, animated: true)` to `setRealEditing(true/false)` instead.

#### Note 1

One problem I found was that when using `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` was that the delete button (⛔️) didn't work anymore. Tapping it did not trigger the confirmation swipe.

I found that there had to exist a `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` with a `UIContextualAction` that was initialized with `UIContextualAction(style: .destructive)` (i.e had destructive style). This is the item that is then used for displaying the delete confirmation.

However I did not want that item to be visible when the regular swipe actions were used, so to only show it one "real edit mode" I used the `realEditMode` flag.

This worked for me and didn't seem too hacky. If anything more official pops up I'm more than happy to change the accepted answer.

Comment: did you ever figure out why the delete button doesn't work when these swipe actions are configured (your Note 1)? I'm asking as I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: @MER no, I did not go any further than the outlined solution I'm afraid. The solution worked fine for me so didn't try to understand why it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52101379/580850):

Simply overriding tableView(_:willBeginEditingRowAt:) will prevent the call to setEditing(true) at the begin of a cell swipe.

Overriding tableView(_:didEndEditingRowAt:) prevents the call to setEditing(false) at the end of the cell editing.